# Menu in application with multiple content views, should I create classes for each one

Tags: android

I have application which has a menu, the menu is made of 4-5 buttons, like: Single player, Multi player, High scores... When I click on some button it opens a new view and each view currently is made in a separate class, but I was wondering it will be easier if I can make two views in a single class, for example when I click "Signle player" I get a new window with 3 buttons for: Easy, Normal, Hard. Is it better to do those 2 views in one class and how to do it ?

```
 singleplayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.single_player);
        }
    });
```

If I write this in the main menu class then when I click single player it will open that window but when I click "Back" it will exit the application instead of to go back to main menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the priviledge to comment right now but why not use fragments

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.timedifferencelayout, null);
    }
}
```

and to add one

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, new MainFragment()).commit();
```

and on back pressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently my class extends Activity and when I instead of that extend Fragment it creates all sorts of errors, I guess I will have to read alot before I can use this

Comment: Just extend AppCompactActivity or FragmentActivity